# Removing duplication in RSpec and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am learning to use **RSpec 3.4** for testing, and **Factory Girl 4.7** for fixture replacement.

There is a lot of duplication in my code and I don't really know how to make it cleaner.

Here is a code example:

**user_licence_factory.rb**

```
factory :user_licence do
  email 'user@email.com'

  trait :standard do
    product_id 1
    licence_key '12345'
  end
end
```

**product_factory.rb**

```
factory :product do
  trait :primary_product do
    id 1
    name 'Primary Product'
  end
end
```

**site_licence_factory.rb**

```
factory :site_licence do
  email 'user@email.com'

  trait :primary_product
    product_id 1
    uuid 'xxx'
  end
end
```

**api_controller_spec.rb**

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let!(:main_product) { FactoryGirl.create(:product, :primary_product) }
let!(:licence) do
  FactoryGirl.create(:user_licence, :standard, email: user.email)
end
let!(:linked_licence) { FactoryGirl.create(:site_licence, :primary_product, email: user.email) }

it 'validates the licence key'
```

This is a simplified version, becase I have multiple products, and licence type, and then products tied to the licence.

When I need to test the API, I need to create the user, a product that belongs to a licence, and a licence for that user that belongs to that product.
Each user can have many licences and each licence belongs to one unique product.

My desired workflow would be, create a user and create a licence for the user. By doing that only one product would be created, even if I create 10 licences.

Thanks

Comment: I would have to see the actual specs to get a better idea, but depending on how your specs are grouped what you could do is just reassign the product on the license at the beginning of each test so you only need to have one user and one license.

Comment: The specs are all there in the question, what else do you need?

Comment: I was referring to the segments of your specs that have your expect statements.